# Select from related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

So in my data base i have 2 tables related:
The fields are id, name, price and a int so i know if they a all sold or not

fruits

```
|IDfruit| name  | price  | sold  |
|  1    |orange | 5      | 0
|  2    |apple  | 10     | 0
|  3    |grape  | 15     | 1
|  4    |lemon  | 7      | 1
```

primary key is IDfruit

images

```
|IDimage| url        | idfruit_image
| 1     | image1.png |     1      
| 2     | image2.png |     1
| 3     | image3.png |     2
| 4     | image4.png |     3    
| 5     | image5.png |     4
| 6     | image6.png |     4 
| 7     | image7.png |     4
```

IDimage is primary key and idfruit_image is a foreign key that references IDfruit

The result i want is all fruits and the FIRST image of each fruit.

So what i've done is

```
select fruits.*, url , idfruit_image 
from fruits,images 
where IDfruit = idfruit_image;
```

This return all fruits and all images of each fruit, but i would like just one image of each fruit, how can i achieve this?

And what if i want everything from all sold fruits and just the first image of each one

Comment: If there are multiple images, which image do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` to get one row per fruit, and an aggregation function to select one of the images.

```
SELECT f.*, MAX(url) AS url
FROM fruits AS f
LEFT JOIN images AS i ON f.idfruit = i.idfruit_image
GROUP BY f.idfruit
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want the first image per fruit, *first* being defined as: the image with the smallest `idimage`.

If you just want the url of the image, a correlated subquery should be an acceptable solution:

```
select 
    f.*, 
    (
        select i.url 
        from images i 
        where i.idfruit_image = f.idfruit 
        order by i.idimage 
        limit 1
    ) url
from fruits f
```

If you want the whole image record, one option is to join, then filter with a subquery:

```
select f.*, i.*
from fruits f
inner join images i on i.idimage = (
    select min(i1.idimage) from images i1 where i1.idfruit_image = f.idfruit
)
```

Finally: in MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        f.*, 
        i.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by i.idfruit_image order by i.idimage) as rn
    from fruits f
    inner join images i on i.idfruit_image = f.idfruit
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: All worked as a charm tyvm. Are there any differences between using row_number and select min? Like performancewise